# Powershell teams message multiple lines

Tags: powershell

Currently I have this code

```
$body = ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 2 @{

text = '1s line text'
2nd line text

}

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $myURI -Method Post -body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

But how can I Make it so it makes the text in two rows. so 1s line text and then on another line the 2nd line text.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a newline in between the two lines. You can do this using:

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2 @{
    text = '1st line text' + [Environment]::NewLine + '2nd line text'
}
```

Or

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2 @{
    text = "1st line text`r`n2nd line text"
}
```

Or

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2 @{
text = @"
1st line text
2nd line text
"@
}
```

In all cases, this

```
($body | ConvertFrom-Json).text
```

will return

> ```
> 1st line text
> 2nd line text
> ```